# Replace string with sed in array and store as variable

Tags: arrays, string, bash, sed

If I hard code the csgo path my code works, but if I use a search funtion and replace the directory I searched for using sed my code fails.

```
    #Find directorties of CSGO instances to update
    updatepaths=`find /home/tcagame/ -type f -name "update_csgo.txt"`
    #Splits diretories on space to be read from the array
    updates=($updatepaths)


    #Path to CSGO instances to update
    #csgo="/home/tcagame/user/33/csgo/steam.inf"
    #Creating automated path
    csgo= echo "${updates[0]}" | sed  's,update_csgo.txt,csgo/steam.inf,'

    #Check for updates
    python $updatecheck $csgo > ~/autoupdate/status/updatestatus.txt
```

When I `echo "$csgo"` it creates a new line, I think thats why its not working.

```
/home/tcagame/user/33/csgo/steam.inf
[New Line]
```

This is what I am tryin to achieve in an automated style:

```
python srcupdatecheck /home/tcagame/iceman/206/csgo/steam.inf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `mapfile` to read the lines of `find` output into an array is safer than relying on word splitting: the only trouble you'll have is if a filename contains a newline character.

```
mapfile -t updates < <(find /home/tcagame/ -type f -name "update_csgo.txt")
```

Here, you only need parameter expansion, not sed:

```
csgo="${updates[0]%update_csgo.txt}csgo/steam.inf"
```

Or, let find do more of the heavy lifting for you:

```
mapfile -t update_dirs < <(
    find /home/tcagame/ -type f -name "update_csgo.txt" -exec dirname '{}' \;
)
csgo="${update_dirs[0]}/csgo/steam.inf"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The first answer was best suited for my script. As I was using the $csgo in other parts of my code.